# RSA Encryption using the user-defined keys in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am trying to encrypt a small amount of data using RSA algorithm using python. The problem is I have the public and private RSA key. Both are stored in .pem and .ppk respectively. I am not able to find any help in google which will help me encrypt it using my keys. All the code and examples I saw generates its own keys. Is there a way where I can use my own keys to encrypt and decrypt the data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rsa module .

```
import rsa
with open('public.ppm','r') as  key_pub_file:
     key_pub = key_pub_file.read()
     message = "hello".encode('utf8')
     enc_msg = rsa.encrypt(message, key_pub)
     print(enc_msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5 as Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5
from base64 import b64decode,b64encode
f1 = open('public.ppm','r')
pubkey = f1.read() 
#pubkey = 'MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBA3UAWE0HSQ77CwP/8UbX07W2XKwng/nMT1R7vaz+2EeNR/FitFXwIDAQAB'
msg = "test"
keyDER = b64decode(pubkey)
keyPub = RSA.importKey(keyDER)
cipher = Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5.new(keyPub)
cipher_text = cipher.encrypt(msg.encode())
emsg = b64encode(cipher_text)
print(emsg)
```

While trying, I found this code to be working. msg variable contains the data to be encrypted and pubkey contains the public key which ill be taking from ppm file.